# Box with subtext in an equation

Tags: math-mode, equations

I would like to do something like the boxes in the equation below
[image: figure]

But I have no idea how to implement this in Tex. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option (the example illustrates the size change according to the math style):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newlength\boxln

\newcommand\MyBox{{%
  \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
  \fbox{\phantom{\text{\raisebox{-0.25\boxln}{\rule{\boxln}{\boxln}}}}}}%
}
\newcommand\TwoBox[2]{%
\mathchoice
  {\setlength\boxln{1.5em}{\text{\footnotesize#1}}\,\,\underset{\textstyle\text{\raisebox{-0.3em}{\footnotesize#2}}}{\MyBox}}
  {\setlength\boxln{1em}{\scriptscriptstyle\text{#1}}\,\underset{\scriptscriptstyle\text{\raisebox{-0em}{#2}}}{\MyBox}}
  {\setlength\boxln{0.5em}{\scriptscriptstyle\text{#1}}\,\underset{\text{\raisebox{-0.1em}{#2}}}{\MyBox}}
  {\setlength\boxln{0.5em}{\scriptscriptstyle\text{#1}}\,\underset{\text{\raisebox{-0.25em}{#2}}}{\MyBox}}
}

\begin{document}

\[
\TwoBox{P}{A}\longleftrightarrow\TwoBox{A}{P}
\]

Some text $
\TwoBox{P}{A}\longleftrightarrow\TwoBox{A}{P}\quad
M_{\TwoBox{P}{A}\longleftrightarrow\TwoBox{A}{P}}\quad
A_{M_{\TwoBox{P}{A}\longleftrightarrow\TwoBox{A}{P}}}
$ and some more

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! How can I change the size of the letters P and A? I would like them to be somewhat smaller.

Comment: @AnneO'Nyme Do you want to reduce the size for all math styles or just for displaystyle (the first one in my example code)?

Comment: For both I just want the relative size of the letters P and A to be smaller compared to the box.

Comment: @AnneO'Nyme I've updated my answer reducing the size for the letters.

Answer (score 5):

Here's my solution; the box has the same height as `\sum` in text style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\boxop}{\mathop{\mathpalette\doboxop\relax}}
\newcommand{\doboxop}[2]{%
  \sbox0{$\ifx#1\displaystyle\textstyle\else#1\fi\sum$}%
  \dimen0=\ht0 \advance\dimen0 \dp0
  \vcenter{\fboxsep=-\fboxrule
    \hbox{\fbox{\rule{0pt}{\dimen0}\rule{\dimen0}{0pt}}}
  }%
}
\newcommand{\nymefirst}[1]{\mathpalette\donymefirst{#1}}
\newcommand{\donymefirst}[2]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{$
    \ifx#1\displaystyle\scriptstyle\else
      \ifx#1\textstyle\scriptstyle\else
    \scriptscriptstyle\fi\fi #2
  $}}%
}
\newcommand{\nymebox}[2]{%
  \nymefirst{#1}\mspace{2mu}{\boxop\limits_{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
&\text{Display}\qquad && \nymebox{P}{A}\leftrightarrow\nymebox{A}{P} \\
&\text{Text}          && \textstyle \nymebox{P}{A}\leftrightarrow\nymebox{A}{P} \\
&\text{Script}        && \scriptstyle \nymebox{P}{A}\leftrightarrow\nymebox{A}{P}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If we change the definition of `\boxop` to

```
\newcommand{\doboxop}[2]{%
  \sbox0{$\ifx#1\displaystyle\textstyle\else#1\fi\sum$}%
  \dimen0=\ht0 \advance\dimen0 \dp0
  \vcenter{\fboxsep=-\fboxrule
    \hbox{\fbox{\rule{0pt}{\dimen0}\rule{\dimen0}{0pt}}}
  }%
}
```

the box will grow in display style, giving

[image]

Answer (score 3):

EDITED to preserve math style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,stackengine,graphicx,scalerel}
\stackMath
\def\mybox{\scalebox{2.3}{\raisebox{\dimexpr-1.5\LMpt-0.5pt}{$\SavedStyle\square$}}}
\newcommand\labelbox[2]{\ThisStyle{\,\,\raisebox{\dimexpr1.5\LMpt+1pt}{$\SavedStyle_#1$}%
  \stackunder[2pt]{\mybox}{\SavedStyle_#2}\,\,}}
\begin{document}
\[X\quad\labelbox{P}{A} \longleftrightarrow \labelbox{A}{P}\]
\[\scriptstyle X\quad\labelbox{P}{A} \longleftrightarrow \labelbox{A}{P}\]
\[\scriptscriptstyle X\quad\labelbox{P}{A} \longleftrightarrow \labelbox{A}{P}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

ORIGINAL SOLUTION:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx}
\def\mybox{\scalebox{2.3}{\raisebox{-2pt}{$\square$}}}
\newcommand\labelbox[2]{%
  \,\,\scriptstyle\mathrm{#1}\stackunder[2pt]{\mybox}{\scriptsize#2}\,\,}
\begin{document}
$\labelbox{P}{A} \longleftrightarrow \labelbox{A}{P}$
\end{document}
```

[image]